# how do i create http visible files from java web application?

Tags: java, file, jsp, servlets

How can I create files visible by http protocol from java web application in web/myFiles folder ?

Is this even possible ?

for the following code :

```
String realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    System.out.println(realPath);

    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter( realPath + "\\myFiles\\test.txt"));
        out.write("aString\nthis is a\nttest");
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception " + e);

    }
```

i keep getting the error :

```
Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\Andrei\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\SemanticCashUpV1.0\build\web\myFiles\test.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: The exception means your code is working, but you didn't create or deploy the myFiles directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes possible,

You need to create file in public web area.

near to `WEB-INF` Dir.

you can get path to public web space by

`request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");`

Comment: how to get server real/absolute path for file creation ?